# Intent to get the UID of application uninstalled

Tags: android, android-intent, uid

i've a receiver that is fired on any application uninstall. I want to get the UID of the application . Currently i got the package name that was uninstalled but when i'm trying to get the UID, its returning null. Currently, i'm getting the UID of any package from following code.

```
public String getID(String pckg_name) {
        ApplicationInfo ai = null;
        String id = "";
        try {
            ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(pckg_name, 0);
            id = "" + ai.uid;
        } catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
            id = "";
        }

        return id;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get the UID after the package has been uninstalled because it is no longer there. The broadcast `Intent` is sent **after** the package has been removed. However...

...from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED):

The broadcast `Intent` that is broadcast when the application is removed (uninstalled) contains an extra `EXTRA_UID` containing the integer uid previously assigned to the package.

Comment: implemented the same!! was about to answer my question:)